# Can't create pipeline in Amazon Elastic Transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

In AWS Elastic Transcoder i want to create a new pipeline.But when i am trying to do that, got following error that shows in image.[image]

What is the permission needed to create a pipeline?
How can i get that permission or how admin can give me such permission ?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually telling you, its the LiatRoles role, so it can list the roles to generate this list :)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListRoles.html

Comment: It looks like you're logged in as the user "appu" -- you need the "iam:ListRoles" permission